# When launching google apps from command line , don't want to open google chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome-app

When I launch google apps[which is developed by myself] from command line, for example:

```
chrome.exe --load-and-launch-app="C:\Users\KyawKhaing\Desktop\chrome\Chrome App\Example2"
```

After I run this, I see Google Chrome Browser open first follow by my google chrome apps launch. I don't want to open google chrome browser when I launch a chrome app. Any one know the solution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `--silent-launch` argument.

```
chrome.exe --silent-launch --load-and-launch-app="C:\Users\KyawKhaing\Desktop\chrome\Chrome App\Example2"
```

Comment: You need to explain what this change do. Don't post only script commands in the answer without it.

Comment: According to the [switch list](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) compiled from source code, this switch does not exist in the current Chrome version. Are you sure?

Comment: The switch does exist and works as specified.
See: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#silent-launch

Comment: The actual switch which is intended for this purpose is --no-startup-window, but that switch seems to be buggy (maybe it needs to be combined with a switch that prevents chrome from auto-closing when there are no windows?), and --silent-launch works well.

Answer (score 0):

As I was running automation scripts in java, i did notice that chrome did not open using command prompt.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe \"http:\\www.google.com\"");
```

From Windows  7, I fixed the problem with the following steps:

1. Go to the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
2. Right-click on chrome.exe
3. Select Properties
4. Select the Compatibility TAB
5. Click on the "Change settings for all users" button
6. Make sure to put a Check Mark on "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and
7. Select "Windows 7" from the drop down list.

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do it currently. It is a reasonable feature request! You can make feature requests at http://crbug.com/new

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug already logged for this, see http://crbug.com/175381.

We are working on making app background pages keep the browser process alive; once this is done we can fix this bug. The problem currently is due to the way the process is kept alive - if we don't show the browser window the process exits between loading the app and the app opening a window.

Comment: I got the answer.I can launch google apps from command line but no more google chrome brower open. The solution is that I use "app-id" to run chrome app instead of "load-and-launch-app". Eg;C:\Users\Kyaw Khaing\Desktop\chrome\Chrome Portable\GoogleChromePortable\chrome.exe --app-id=gahhbpgogngoonaeokehefocgedggjgd

Comment: Ah, yeah. That's a great point, and gives me an idea for a much simpler fix for that bug! Note this won't work if chrome is already running and you want to reload a newer version of the app, which is what we added --load-and-launch-app for.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can do that. The browser is the environment of the app. Its like trying to run a windows app, without running windows. The app depends on the browser. You can't open the app without opening the browser first. Sorry. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank your answer. Why I asked this question is that , after I can see my google chrome app, I can close google chrome browser , nothing effect on the chrome app. Any way to run google chrome browser as back ground thread for google chrome app?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is a way to do that. Maybe the other way around, but... You can try and find some way, to close the chrome browser, when open the app programmatically, but I'm not sure it is possible. Sorry.

Comment: As mentioned above this should work bug currently doesn't due to some limitations in the chrome process's lifetime bookkeeping. We'll fix it hopefully for M31. Note the browser can currently operate independently of its windows, e.g. Mac works like this once you close the last window, and if background mode is operational it also works like this.